# Compiled documents appearing with extra wide right margin

Tags: margins, templates, octavo

This problem appeared after I installed XeTeX from TeX Live 2011. Now, many of my files are rendering with a very wide right-hand margin.

Here is some sample code:

```
\documentclass{octavo}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum
\end{document}
```

When running `pdflatex` or `xelatex` on the file, the right 60% of the file is white and the text is all to the right. With `xelatex`, the output PDF always ignores my custom page dimensions and only gives A4 paper with my text printed very small in the top left corner.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Octavo does not set `\pdfpagewidth` and `\pdfpageheight`.  You need to do it yourself, for example

```
\documentclass[crown]{octavo}
\pdfpagewidth=5in
\pdfpageheight=7.5in
\usepackage{lipsum}
\begin{document}
    \lipsum[1-12]
\end{document}
```

(see http://www.trussel.com/books/booksize.htm or octavo source code for other classic sizes).